# How do I get DVDs to play in Debian?

Tags: debian, dvd

I just installed Debian Live and movie or video DVDs do not play. Totem gives me this error:

> Could not read from resource.

Opening the disk in VLC has no response. How can I play DVDs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DVDs are usually encrypted, and you need to install a special codec to read them.

```
apt-get install libdvdcss2
```

This package should do the trick.

Comment: And you need to add a source for libdvdcss! Either [Debian Unofficial](http://unofficial.debian-maintainers.org/) or [Debian Multimedia](http://www.debian-multimedia.org/).

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is unfortunately now outdated. `libdvdcss2` has been replaced by `libdvd-pkg` , which need to be installed using `dpkg-reconfigure`.
[This tutorial](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/installing-plugins-codecs-libdvdcss-in-debian-ubuntu-linux/) details the step, but, in short, you should [first make sure you have "contrib" packages repository among your sources, then] enter, as root:

```
sudo apt-get install libdvd-pkg
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

and, eventually,

```
sudo apt-get install regionset
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra
```